# Magento product categories disappear when trying to add new products

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

This is an odd issue. All of our categories are showing up in the Magento admin category area but when we try and add new products we cannot assign them to specific categories because they don't show up. I have tried manually adding a simple product and a configurable product but the only category that I have available is the default category, none of my other categories show up. I have attached a screenshot of the product page and category page listing all our categories. Anyone else have this issue or might be able to point me in the right direction? I have tried flushing the all the cache, nothing seems to work... We are running 1.5.

Thanks for the help.

Photo of adding a product with no categories available.
http://climbhigh.com/images/missing-categoy.png

All of our available categories.
http://climbhigh.com/images/category-list.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE catalog_category_entity SET children_count = "1" WHERE children_count < 1;
```

I had some issues with the children_count being a negative value, and this fixed it for me.